# keep hamburger menu inline with logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hamburger-menu

I'm using the standard navbar bootstrap 4 hamburger menu coming in for smaller screens as par, however, when testing on smaller screens it wraps underneath the navbar-brand location and I can't seem to find the particlar part of css to keep it floating on the same row as the logo. The problem with it is that it obscures the header below it on smaller screens which is not ideal for mobile viewers.

I'm using CDN for the latest bootstrap 4 Beta

Here's the link to the page I'm playing with: [link:](http://saturn-global.com/superfastremovals/)

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Many thanks!

The HTML I've got in is as follows:

HTML:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid navbrand">
    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/sflogo.png" style="width:80%;height:80%;"/></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hamburgerMenu"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="hamburgerMenu" style="opacity:1;">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <header id="home-section">
  <img src="img/headbg.jpg" style="width:100%; height:auto;" />
  </header>
  <div class="underhead">
     We have "Goods In Transit" Insurance!<br />
     <span style="font-weight:normal;">Rest assured all your items will be covered during your move.</span>
  </div>
```

The CSS is:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #f2e000;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-brand {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #f2e000;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #333;
}

.container .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.navbar {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.nav-link {
    font-weight:bolder;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
    color: #f2e000;
}

#home-section {
margin-top:4.5em;
}

.underhead {
    background:#f2e000;
    color:#333;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:2vw;
    width:100%;
    padding:20px;
}

@media (max-width:500px) {
    .underhead {
        font-size: 0.8em;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 460px) {
    .navbrand img {
        width:40%;
        height:40%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code to the question. Stackoverflow is a collaborative website and more people could benefit from answers to similar issues you're having at the moment. Please read: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The `<br>` and `<img>` tags do not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: You're right Rob, I'm oldschool I guess and stills tuck on the old pre html4 days! Hah!

Comment: HTML never had a closing slash for tags. Don't know what you mean about pre-HTML4. It's never been specified so I don't know why you would have ever done that. I've been doing this for 17 years and have never put slashes there. It's definitely not in any HTML spec.

Comment: It was used for xhtml for void tags, obviously no longer needed today but old habits die hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HI you can make the same by tweaking  css changes :

```
 @media (max-width: 575px) {
    button.navbar-toggler {
        position: absolute !important;
        right: 10px !important;
        top: 14px !important;
    }
 }
```

Comment: This did fix it for mobile, not on Firefox; not that it matters to be honest! I should have used absolute position, a bit of a blonde moment! Thanks for that!

Comment: Hi I have checked it on firefox too and it seems like working fine there. :)

Comment: Could be my browser, I run the dev version of it so it can be buggy, which firefox seems to be these days! Thanks for checking buddy!